# While upgrading my react project from material-V4 to MUI-V5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was upgrading my project from material-ui V4.11.2 to mui V5.

got below mentioned error

The `styles` argument provided is invalid.
You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.

[image]

Comment: https://v5-0-6.mui.com/guides/migration-v4/

Please follow the migration guide. If a specific step doesnt work, then add a code block.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors[https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551].